# Как сделать Redirect Razor страницы на саму себя?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, redirect, razor

У меня есть страница Razor, которая доступна по [URL](http://localhost:5000/pages/bindings)

Я пытаюсь на этой странице с помощью атрибута `asp-page="bindings"`  перенаправить пользователя снова на неё, но заместь перенаправления на себя происходит перенаправление в `/controllers?page=%2Fpages%2Fbindings"`

Вот код:

```
@page "/pages/bindings"
@model BindingsModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <form asp-page="bindings" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Value #1</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="Data" value="Item 1" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Value #2</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="Data" value="Item 2" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Value #3</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="Data" value="Item 3" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <a class="btn btn-secondary" asp-page="Bindings">Reset</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach (string s in Model.Data.Where(s => s != null))
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item">@s</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@functions {
    public class BindingsModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(Name = "Data")]
        public string[] Data { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это называется "обновить страницу", а зачем это? Странно обновлять то что уже загружено, пустая трата трафика. А вообще, если уж очень хочется, то задача решается на чистом JS https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715123/12888024

Comment: Зачем вам переобновлять страницу? Может у вас поменялись данные, но в UI они не меняются? Если да, то вам нужно вызывать StateHasChanged();